# make search params downcase

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I got help with this code since I am learning how to use params and I want it to be downcase before it start searching. I have already taken care of the downcase on the address when the user submits it.

Where do I put the downcase in the params ?

```
@ads_item_plus_today = @ads_item_plus_today.where(category_id: params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id]

@ads_item_plus_today = @ads_item_plus_today.where("address LIKE ?", "%#{params[:address]}%") if params[:address] && params[:address] != ''
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I have already taken care of the downcase on the address when the user submits it"? If you've already downcased the address param, what are you asking how to do?

Comment: oh sorry, I did take care of the address field where the user submit the adress. Now I wounder how I make it so that if a user search for a address so that it will turn them to downcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either downcase it in-place:

```
if params[:address].present?
  params[:address].downcase!
  @ads_item_plus_today = @ads_item_plus_today.where("address LIKE ?", "%#{params[:address]}%")
end
```

...which will modify the value in `params[:address]` or you can make a copy that's downcased:

```
if params[:address].present?
  address = params[:address].downcase
  @ads_item_plus_today = @ads_item_plus_today.where("address LIKE ?", "%#{address}%")
end
```

...which doesn't change `params[:address]`.

However, you don't necessarily have to do this at all, depending on your database. In many configurations [`LIKE` comparisons in MySQL are case-insensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html) (you can check with [`SHOW COLLATION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-collation.html), or set it on a per-query basis with `COLLATE` ). In PostgreSQL you can use [`ILIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html) instead of `LIKE` to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: Since I will be using postgreSQL I need to look this up. Thank you @jordan

Comment: WARNING!  this ain't gonna work on RUSSIAN, possible other non-english strings... I had to do do ```keyword.mb_chars.downcase```